# facebook share meta tags not working

Tags: facebook-opengraph, facebook-share

No matter what I try I cannot get my facebook share to use open graph meta tags properly. I have scraped my code, used various parameters but no result. It always reads the default. What is the issue?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Online financial planning - fast and free | India</title>

    <meta property="og:url"           content="https://www.kwikplan.com" />
    <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title"         content="Online financial planning - fast and free | India" />
    <meta property="og:description"   content="Build and execute your personal financial plan in minutes - FREE" />
    <meta property="og:image"         content="http://www.kwikplan.com/images/logo.png" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://www.kwikplan.com" data-layout="button" data-mobile-iframe="false"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

OKay, I found the problem. I was adding meta tags in the separate php page for testing but facebook picks only from the landing page. Once I added meta tags on the landing page, it is working.

But now this presents a new problem. If I use these meta tags on the landing page I can use facebook share only once in my site (or multiple ones as well but they will all have the same content). How are these blog sites able to presenta unique/different facebook share button with different content for each article?